# Gambler's Ruin with changing probabilities

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, gambling

I have the following Markov Chain and am trying to evaluate the probability that the Chain reaches state 4 before it returns to state 1, given it starts in state 1. I've seen many typical problems with constant probabilities of p and q, but I am not sure how to approach this style of question.

I have simplified the problem for any readers: $q_x=1-p_x$

$ \left( \begin{array}
qq_1 & p_1  & 0&0 \\
q_2 & 0 & p_2&0 \\
q_3 & 0 & 0&p_3 \\
q_4 & 0 & 0&0\\
 \end{array} \right)$

Would be grateful for any help, thank you!

Comment: What is $x$? ...

Comment: $x$ is a constant, so the answer would have $x$ in it.

Comment: Do you mean *return* to state 1 after leaving it, or does the process stop if they don't move on the first step?

Comment: If it stays in state 1 after the first step, then yes, we have reached state 1.

Comment: So state 1 transitions to state 2 with probability $(\frac12)^x$ - is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't hurt the problem, but your transition matrix isn't square, which doesn't make proper sense; at the Markov chain level, this chain can reach $5$ and doesn't know what to do after it does so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should deal with the fact that your process starts out on the "boundary" and can remain there with positive probability. Thus the probability to hit $1$ first is $1-2^{-x}$ plus $2^{-x}$ times the probability to hit $1$ first starting from $2$. So we have reduced the problem to finding the probability to hit $1$ first starting from $2$.

There is a standard recipe for this. It works as follows. Define $\tau=\min \{ n>0 : X_\tau \in \{ 1,4 \} \}$ and $q(y)=P(X_\tau = 1 | X_0=y)$. (Note that $\tau$ cannot be zero, which is why we had to do the first step "by hand" in the previous paragraph.) Then by conditioning on the first step, we find that $(Lq)(y)=0$ for $y \in \{ 2,3 \}$,$q(1)=1$,$q(4)=0$. Here $L$ is called the generator, which in discrete time is $P-I$ where $P$ is the transition matrix and $I$ is the identity.

I write in this general form because this form works in discrete time+discrete space, continuous time+discrete space (where the generator is again a matrix) and continuous time+continuous space (where the generator is a differential operator).

Comment: So with your first paragraph, are you saying that $P$(reaching state 4 before returning to state 1|start at 1) = $2^{-x}$ * $P$(reaching state 4 before returning to state 1|start at 2)$?

Comment: $P(\text{ we reach state 4 before returning to 1 starting from 1 })=P(\text{ we remain at 1 at the beginning }) + P(\text{ we jump to 2 at the beginning })P(\text{ we reach 4 before returning to 1 starting from 2})$

Comment: That was my understanding of your comment in the answer: if the first step takes us from $1$ to $1$ then the process stops, with us reaching $1$ before $4$. If this isn't the intended interpretation, then we just have $P(\text{ we reach 4 before returning to 1 starting from 2 })$, since we will then always jump to $2$ eventually. (We might have to wait, but this changes nothing.)

Comment: Yes, it can go from 1 to 1 immediately. But I don't intuitively understand how it increases the probability of reaching 4 first. Wouldn't a higher probability of remaining at 1 originally decrease the probability of reaching 4, not increase it?

Comment: That's right: but I'm approaching the problem by getting the probability of hitting $1$ first and then subtracting that from $1$. (Cf. my second sentence.)

Comment: Ok, I'm having trouble understanding the rest of the answer. I have learnt the formula $\frac{q}p^{start}-\frac{q}p^{upper}$ divided by $\frac{q}p^{lower}-\frac{q}p^{upper}$ for constant p and q's (q=1-p), the answer seems to be beyond the scope of my understanding. Does your answer have anything to do with the formula?

Comment: Having dealt with the first step, if you hit $1$ the process stops, and you hit $1$ first, so $q(1)=1$. If you start at $4$ the process stops, and you hit $4$ first, so $q(4)=0$. If you start at $2$, then you hit $1$ with a certain probability and you hit $3$ with a certain probability. So $q(2)$ is a combination of $q(1)$ (which you know) and $q(3)$. $q(3)$ is similarly a combination of $q(2)$ and $q(4)$ (which you know). So now you have a system of two linear equations in two unknowns (the unknowns being $q(2)$ and $q(3)$). This is the same system that I wrote down in terms of $L$.

Comment: @Samantha That formula is what you get when you apply this procedure to the simple random walk. So it is not applicable, but its derivation is applicable.

Comment: @Samantha Yes, I forgot about that detail. So actually the system is even simpler, because it is triangular (after substituting the values of $q(1)$ and $q(4)$).

Comment: @Samantha Looks OK. Now your desired answer was $1-\left ( 1-2^{-x}+2^{-x}q(2) \right )$ (from the first paragraph).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me understand